# fetching from local server in react shows impossible

Tags: reactjs

I've read many docs, even [react docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) on how to fetch data from a local server. For some reason I can't get things moving.

This is the logic of the project:

- I've set up an express server on port 5000
- in this directory created client/ folder, and installed create-react-app
- And started `npm start` on port 3000.

`package.lock` includes the line: `"proxy":"localhost:5000/"` because that's required. I can see the data being received in the network tab.

But it is not displayed, in fact `data` in the next chunk of code, is undefined (yes, undefined, who knows what's happening). This is the function fetching and displaying the data:

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText]=useState("")
  const [data, setData]=useState("")
  useEffect( () => {
    fetch("/elements/"+text)
      .then(res=>{ res.json() })
      .then(data=>{ setData(data) })
      .catch(err=>console.log("cant find that data"))
  }, [text])
  const myF = ()=>{
    let elements = []
    data.forEach(atom => {
      const name=Object.keys(atom)
      elements.push(
        <div key={atom[name].symbol} className="atom">
        <h1>{atom[name]}</h1>
        </div>)
    })
    return elements
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type name here..." value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}/>
    <div className="atomsGrid">
    {data ? myF : <h1>Waiting...</h1> }
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It's like, the data is fetched, but everything on this function is undefined.

Can you give me some ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea because you dont have an return statement, and returning nothing means `undefined`. you can either write `return` or remove the curly braces

```
fetch("/elements/"+text)
  .then(res=> res.json())
  .then(data=>{ setData(data) })
  .catch(err=>console.log("cant find that data"))
```

or with return statement:

```
...
.then(res=> { return res.json() })
...
```